# How do I start my local repository with Git?

Tags: git, github

I signed up with GitHub today and I'm struggling to understand exactly what way I should be using this.

I have downloaded the Git program and I followed the instructions to create a folder which now resides in "c:/user/app data/local/program/git". However, there is no explanation of what to do next.

Should I be developing and saving the files in this directory, or should I be doing something else? This folder seems like completely the wrong place for my project files (why don't I have them in my own directory?) So I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Anyway help appreciated, I can't find any good simple explanations on how to go from start to finish, it assumes I know the workflow for this but I do not.

Comment: http://help.github.com/creating-a-repo/

Comment: see this: [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have a path like that.

Assuming you installed git correctly, you should be able to say

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ git init
$ git remote add origin [github repo] 
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First commit!" 
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: THAT makes sense! So I change to my project directory (for example: c/project/whatever/) then do git init etc? The guide let me to believe I create the directory from the git program and then it leaves me.

okay that makes a lot of sense, thanks! I'll do that.

Comment: @user: Yes, that's how it works. Git stores everything in place, unlike SVN or CVS which use a separate central repository.